How can I get the content of word file or a ppt file in sharepoint in python using ms graph api?
def get_file_content(access_token, site_id, drive_id, file_id):

    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
    
    # URL to fetch the file content
    graph_api_url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives/{drive_id}/items/{file_id}/content'
    
    response = requests.get(graph_api_url, headers=headers)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.content
    else:
        response.raise_for_status()

I have ms word file in this link: https://m365x36241825.sharepoint.com/:w:/s/Contoso/EfdVPx-4F85PoTiVi_vjqD0Bk2qXB_dwapVsC5t600YS-g?e=ejxhi6
which is opening file in ms word
I have a word file in ms word which is on sharepoint and i want to get the content of the file in python using ms graph api.
